# how to set only 4 products of a specific category on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-list

i'm working on magento 1.9 with b-responsive theme. i want to show only 4 product of a specific categoy on my home page but unable to do so.
i have changed the product page and it shows all product without pagination on a single page for every category.

for that i have copied `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` and change the line:

```
$limit = 'all';
```

now it shows all products of that category in one page.but on my home page when i call a block i want to show only 4 product of that category.

Here is my code on my home page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="16" template="catalog/product/list_notoolbar.phtml"}}
```

and it showing all product of that category but i want to show only four products.how can i achieve that.

Comment: hi frinds please visit link:-http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#cms/widget-new-products-list.html

Comment: use this code:-echo this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list.phtml")->setCategoryId('category_id')->toHtml();

Comment: @AshvinMonpara : where to add this code????????

Comment: homepage.phtml use this code

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: i'm using cms block on page as i mention.i'm not using any homepage.phtml

Comment: use this code in :-home.phtml

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: then it will also affect my inner category page??plz can u tell me what this code will do?

Comment: i wiill try same thing frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtm

Answer (score 2):

Try this adding limit, just like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="4" column_count="4" category_id="16" template="catalog/product/list_notoolbar.phtml"}}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but somehow its not working for me.i have 17 products in category_id="16" and its displaying them all.

Comment: Oh too bad. Hmmmm...

Comment: How about limit="4" ? I updated my answer. Kindly try it. :)

Comment: no change same problem... :(

Comment: How about count="4" ? :D

Comment: If it's still not working, try modifying yung .phtml file. I found that this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281060/limit-number-of-products-shown-on-homepage-list-phtml

Comment: count="4" is also not working. i think i have changed Toolbar.php thats the problem

Comment: Oh too bad. Sorry I'm no expert myself. Just trying to help. Check out the solutions in the link I gave. :)